# Excel VBA : Calling a Case result from one sub into another

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below mentioned **case** which i want to integrate into different **sub**s functioning in a UserForm instead of pasting more than once. How can I do that?

- GSMListType is a ComboBox
- AvailableNumberList is a Listbox

  ```
  Sub WsSelector()
              Dim WSLookup as WorkSheet
              With GSMListType
              Select Case .Value
                  Case "A"
                      Set WSLookup = A_Regular
                  Case "A - K"
                      Set WSLookup = A_K
                  Case "A - MOT"
                      Set WSLookup = A_MOT
                      Case "B"
                      Set WSLookup = B_Regular
                  Case "C"
                      Set WSLookup = C_Regular
                  Case "D"
                      Set WSLookup = D_Regular
                  Case "D - DATA"
                      Set WSLookup = D_DATA
                  Case "D - MOT"
                      Set WSLookup = D_MOT
                  Case "E"
                      Set WSLookup = E_Regular
                  Case "F"
                      Set WSLookup = F_Regular
                  Case "G"
                      Set WSLookup = G_Regular
                  Case "H"
                      Set WSLookup = H_Regular
                  Case "I"
                      Set WSLookup = I_Regular
                  Case "J"
                      Set WSLookup = J_Regular
                  Case "J - DATA"
                      Set WSLookup = J_DATA
                  Case "K"
                      Set WSLookup = K_Regular
                  Case "L"
                      Set WSLookup = L_Regular
                  Case "M"
                      Set WSLookup = M_Regular
                  Case "N"
                      Set WSLookup = N_Regular
                  Case "O"
                      Set WSLookup = O_Regular
                  Case "P"
                      Set WSLookup = P_Regular
                  Case "P - MOT"
                      Set WSLookup = P_MOT
                  Case "Q"
                      Set WSLookup = Q_Regular
                  Case "R"
                      Set WSLookup = R_Regular
                  Case "S"
                      Set WSLookup = S_Regular
                  Case "T"
                      Set WSLookup = T_Regular
                  Case "U"
                      Set WSLookup = U_Regular
                  Case "V"
                      Set WSLookup = V_Regular
                  Case "W"
                      Set WSLookup = W_Regular
                  Case "X"
                      Set WSLookup = X_Regular
                  Case "Y"
                      Set WSLookup = Y_Regular
                  Case "Z"
                      Set WSLookup = Z_Regular
              End Select
          End With
  ```

  End Sub

The above mentioned code should be imported into different subs one of which contains the below mentioned code:

```
Private Sub GSMListType_Change()
    Dim TypeLookup As Long, WSLookup As Worksheet
    'If listing has changed, clear AvailableNumberList and insert new data
    If GSMListType.ListIndex > -1 Then

Call SheetSelector

TypeLookup = Application.CountIf(WSLookup.Range("A:E"), GSMListType.Value)

        With AvailableNumberList
            .Clear
            For k = 2 To TypeLookup + 1
                .AddItem WSLookup.Range("A" & k).Value
            Next k
        End With
    End If
    Set WSLookup = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry but are you asking to move `WsSelector` into multiple subs without neededing to copy and paste it into the subs?

Comment: @BradyK yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change the WsSelector sub to a function that returns the name of the desired worksheet object?

```
Function WsSelector(sTYP As String)
    Select Case sTYP
        Case "A"
            WsSelector = A_Regular.Name
        Case "A - K"
            WsSelector = A_K.Name
        Case "A - MOT"
            WsSelector = A_MOT.Name
        Case "Etc..."
            'Etc...
            'Etc...
        Case Else
            WsSelector = vbNullString
    End Select
End Function
```

This can now be called when setting the selected worksheet.

```
Private Sub GSMListType_Change()
    Set WSLookup = Sheets(WsSelector(GSMListType.Value))
    'lots of code here
    Set WSLookup = Nothing
End Sub
```